# Is there a way to browse through the .pdf with a keyboard in quicklook?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

Is there a way to browse through the .pdf with a keyboard in quicklook?

Then I am trying to use an arrow keys, it changes quicklook file, not the contents of the current file. Is there a way to use quicklook with keyboard only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible with the stock Quick Look. However, this paid app / quick look plugin makes many file formats, including PDFs, searchable: https://apps.apple.com/app/peek-quick-look-extension/id1554235898. I would assume, but not 100% sure (I don't have the app), whether the regular shift-arrow combo works for selecting text. Searching the PDF is supported, too. I found the app on [quicklookplugings.com](https://quicklookplugins.com)

WARNING: after further investigation, PDF is NOT SUPPORTED. Do not spend your money if you are hoping to use this on PDFs or any other of the incompatible file types.

Answer (score 3):

Once the QuickLook thumbnail has focus, then the arrow keys (and Page Up/Down, Home/End keys) will move through the document.

This can be done either by clicking on one of the thumbnails in the Quicklook preview (it will then be highlighted); or by pressing TAB, which will do the same thing.

Comment: Tip of the hat to @jayfehr, who submitted a correct answer but then deleted it.